# Oracle PL/SQL Functions: "Invalid Datatype"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00902

The following function checks to see if a zip code is present in a table called ZIPCODE:

```
create or replace function zip_does_not_exist(i_zip in zipcode.zip%type)
return boolean
as
v_zip zipcode.zip%type;
begin
select zip into v_zip
from zipcode
where zip = i_zip;
if v_zip is not null then
return false;
else
return true;
end if;
end;
/
```

The schema for the ZIPCODE table is as follows: 
[image: ZIPCODE]

To test this function, I issued the following statement which should return false as the zip code passed as an argument is present in the ZIPCODE table:

```
select zip_does_not_exist('00914') from dual;
```

However, I receive this message when trying to run this code:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

This should not be happening, as '00914' is the proper datatype needed as an argument (varchar2(5)). Why am I receiving this message?

Comment: To explain Barbaros's answer a little further: PL/SQL and (Oracle's dialect of) SQL are closely integrated, but they are not the same. Perhaps the most significant difference is that SQL does not have the `boolean` data type, while PL/SQL does. You may ask "what good is it in PL/SQL if I can't use it." The answer is "you **can** use it, but only in other PL/SQL code - not in SQL". If you need to use a value like that in SQL code (and often you do), make the return data type `number` and the return values 0 and 1 (for false and true), or `char(1)` with values `'F', 'T'` or maybe `'N', 'Y'`.

Comment: @mathguy thank you for nice explanation colleague(mathematician).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to create the stored procedure as :

```
create or replace function zip_does_not_exist(i_zip in zipcode.zip%type)
  return pls_integer as
  v_zip zipcode.zip%type;
begin
  select zip into v_zip from zipcode where zip = i_zip;
  if v_zip is not null then
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Then  you'll be successful to call :

```
select zip_does_not_exist('00914') from dual;
```

Since, a boolean can not be set as returning variable for a sql statement.